# How to solve errors in flutter app uses google maps?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-maps, dart

I want to build an app with google maps service and I found many tutorials regarding this but the mostly one fits my need this one [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@zeh.henrique92/google-maps-flutter-marker-circle-and-polygon-c71f4ea64498) I'm trying to build this app, the app has 2 files one main.dart and the another is goomap.dart the main dart code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:maps/pages/goomap.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Location location = new Location();
  bool _serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
  LocationData _locationData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkLocationPermission();
  }

  // Check Location Permissions, and get my location
  void _checkLocationPermission() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Studyng Maps - Zeh'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900], 
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => _locationData != null ? Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GooMap(location: _locationData,))) : null,
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          label: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Open Maps',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.map,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ],
          )),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Study of google maps - Zeh',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'App to study some features of google maps: Testing markers, polygons, polylines and circles',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

And the other file (goomap) code is :

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GooMap extends StatefulWidget {
  //GooMap({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final LocationData location;
  GooMap({this.location});

  @override
  _GooMapState createState() => _GooMapState();
}

class _GooMapState extends State<GooMap> {
  // Location
  LocationData _locationData;

  // Maps
  Set<Marker> _markers = HashSet<Marker>();
  Set<Polygon> _polygons = HashSet<Polygon>();
  Set<Circle> _circles = HashSet<Circle>();
  GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  BitmapDescriptor _markerIcon;
  List<LatLng> polygonLatLngs = List<LatLng>();
  double radius;

  //ids
  int _polygonIdCounter = 1;
  int _circleIdCounter = 1;
  int _markerIdCounter = 1;

  // Type controllers
  bool _isPolygon = true; //Default
  bool _isMarker = false;
  bool _isCircle = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // If I want to change the marker icon:
    // _setMarkerIcon();
    _locationData = widget.location;
  }

  // This function is to change the marker icon
  void _setMarkerIcon() async {
    _markerIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/farm.png');
  }

  // Draw Polygon to the map
  void _setPolygon() {
    final String polygonIdVal = 'polygon_id_$_polygonIdCounter';
    _polygons.add(Polygon(
      polygonId: PolygonId(polygonIdVal),
      points: polygonLatLngs,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeColor: Colors.yellow,
      fillColor: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.15),
    ));
  }

  // Set circles as points to the map
  void _setCircles(LatLng point) {
    final String circleIdVal = 'circle_id_$_circleIdCounter';
    _circleIdCounter++;
    print(
        'Circle | Latitude: ${point.latitude}  Longitude: ${point.longitude}  Radius: $radius');
    _circles.add(Circle(
        circleId: CircleId(circleIdVal),
        center: point,
        radius: radius,
        fillColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
        strokeWidth: 3,
        strokeColor: Colors.redAccent));
  }

  // Set Markers to the map
  void _setMarkers(LatLng point) {
    final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
    _markerIdCounter++;
    setState(() {
      print(
          'Marker | Latitude: ${point.latitude}  Longitude: ${point.longitude}');
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(markerIdVal),
          position: point,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  // Start the map with this marker setted up
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _googleMapController = controller;

    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('0'),
          position: LatLng(-20.131886, -47.484488),
          infoWindow:
              InfoWindow(title: 'Roça', snippet: 'Um bom lugar para estar'),
          //icon: _markerIcon,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _fabPolygon() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: () {
        //Remove the last point setted at the polygon
        setState(() {
          polygonLatLngs.removeLast();
        });
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.undo),
      label: Text('Undo point'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Studying Maps - Zeh'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        ),
        floatingActionButton:
            polygonLatLngs.length > 0 && _isPolygon ? _fabPolygon() : null,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude),
                zoom: 16,
              ),
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              markers: _markers,
              circles: _circles,
              polygons: _polygons,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              onTap: (point) {
                if (_isPolygon) {
                  setState(() {
                    polygonLatLngs.add(point);
                    _setPolygon();
                  });
                } else if (_isMarker) {
                  setState(() {
                    _markers.clear();
                    _setMarkers(point);
                  });
                } else if (_isCircle) {
                  setState(() {
                    _circles.clear();
                    _setCircles(point);
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      onPressed: () {
                        _isPolygon = true;
                        _isMarker = false;
                        _isCircle = false;
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Polygon',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      onPressed: () {
                        _isPolygon = false;
                        _isMarker = true;
                        _isCircle = false;
                      },
                      child: Text('Marker',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white))),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      onPressed: () {
                        _isPolygon = false;
                        _isMarker = false;
                        _isCircle = true;
                        radius = 50;
                        return showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            child: AlertDialog(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                              title: Text(
                                'Choose the radius (m)',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              content: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  child: Material(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map),
                                        hintText: 'Ex: 100',
                                        suffixText: 'meters',
                                      ),
                                      keyboardType:
                                          TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                      onChanged: (input) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          radius = double.parse(input);
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Ok',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                      child: Text('Circle',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I have these error :

```
error: The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:202)
error: The method 'GooMap' isn't defined for the type '_HomePageState'. (undefined_method at [mappolygon] lib/main.dart:52)
error: The function 'run' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [mappolygon] integration_test/app_test.dart:14)
error: The function 'main' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [mappolygon] integration_test/app_test.dart:19)
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:maps/pages/goomap.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [mappolygon] lib/main.dart:3)
warning: The parameter 'builder' is required. (missing_required_param at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:200)
info: Unused import: 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart'. (unused_import at [mappolygon] integration_test/app_test.dart:10)
info: The value of the field '_markerIcon' isn't used. (unused_field at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:26)
info: The value of the field '_googleMapController' isn't used. (unused_field at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:25)
info: The import of 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart' is unnecessary because all of the used elements are also provided by the import of 'package:flutter/material.dart'. (unnecessary_import at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:2)
info: The declaration '_setMarkerIcon' isn't referenced. (unused_element at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:49)
info: The declaration '_onMapCreated' isn't referenced. (unused_element at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:98)
info: 'RaisedButton.RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:173)
info: 'RaisedButton.RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:193)
info: 'RaisedButton.RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:184)
info: 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:173)
info: 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:193)
info: 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:184)
info: 'List.List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:27)
info: 'FlatButton.FlatButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:229)
info: 'FlatButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre.. (deprecated_member_use at [mappolygon] goomap.dart:229)
```

I don't know how to solve these issues can you helps please?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to below code

```
class MapDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 /*Controller*/
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  /*Variable declaration*/
  bool customFlag = false;
  BitmapDescriptor customIcon1;


 /*Custom Marker for Maps*/
  createMarker(context) {
    if (customIcon1 == null) {
      ImageConfiguration configuration = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);
      BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, ImagePaths.dcGlobe) /* ImagePaths.dcGlobe i san asset image */
          .then((icon) {
        customIcon1 = icon;
      });
    }
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createMarker(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          LocationMaps(
            mapController: mapController,
            customFlag: customFlag,
            customIcon1: customIcon1,
            longitudeValues: 85,
            latitudeValues: 12.0,
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocationMaps extends StatelessWidget {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  bool customFlag;
  final BitmapDescriptor customIcon1;
  final longitudeValues;
  final latitudeValues;

  LocationMaps({
    Key key,
    this.mapController,
    this.customFlag,
    this.customIcon1,
    this.longitudeValues,
    this.latitudeValues,
  }) : super(key: key);

  double locationLatitude = 0.0;
  double locationLongitude = 0.0;

  LatLng _center;
  List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    locationLatitude = double.parse(latitudeValues);
    locationLongitude = double.parse(longitudeValues);
    _center = LatLng(locationLatitude, locationLongitude);
    _markers.add(Marker(
        icon: customFlag == true ? customIcon1 : null,
        markerId: MarkerId(''),
        position: LatLng(locationLatitude, locationLongitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: '')));
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      child: Container(
        color: AppColors.creamColor,
        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(120.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: GoogleMap(
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: (Platform.isAndroid) ? true : false,
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _center,
                    zoom: 13.0,
                  ),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


``
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I got many errors.